# A XMLHttp Request in the browser

Tags: javascript, error-handling, rest

Building on a previous [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214002/xmlhttprequest-in-the-browser) and an attempt to write a comprehensive `XMLHttpRequest` example that covers all kinds of possible errors and return them to caller gracefully instead of a crash.

```
function Remote() {}

Remote.upload = function(formData, progressHandler) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.addEventListener("error", function(event){
            reject({code: 0, message: "A network error occurred.", event: event});
        });
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler);
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 0) { // exclude status 0
                try {
                    xhr.status == 200 ? resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response)) : reject(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } catch(error) {
                    reject({code: 0, message: "JSON parsing error.", body: xhr.response});
                }
            }
        });
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
};

function progressHandler(event) {
    if(event.lengthComputable) {
        console.log((event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0));
    }
}
```

Here in this example, I've added a check in the `readystatechange` not to handle status 0 errors since event handler can be triggered with all sorts of those errors, whether invalid certificate, offline or request getting suppressed. (Limitation: Can't figure out the exact error scenario hence the generic Network error message.

- 200 status is success as suggested by the REST contract so it's hard coded.
- JSON parsing error is also a possibility to handle any issues.
- Code is meant to be backward compatible for older browsers.

Hope the code is comprehensive and takes care of all corners.